# how can i use "npm install ts-node-dev -D" in termux?

Tags: typescript, npm, termux

```
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall symlink
npm ERR! path ../acorn/bin/acorn
npm ERR! dest /storage/emulated/0/bot-baiano/node_modules/.bin/acorn
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../acorn/bin/acorn' -> '/storage/emulated/0/bot-baiano/node_modules/.bin/acorn'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../acorn/bin/acorn' -> '/storage/emulated/0/bot-baiano/node_modules/.bin/acorn'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'symlink',
npm ERR!   path: '../acorn/bin/acorn',
npm ERR!   dest: '/storage/emulated/0/bot-baiano/node_modules/.bin/acorn'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.npm/_logs/2022-05-27T14_44_58_844Z-debug-0.log
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because you are trying to install packages in your phone storage (*/storage/emulated*). Your phone does'n have full access there. You wont be able, for instance, to create *symlinks* there. It's explained at the [termux documentation](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Internal_and_external_storage).

Then, it's recommended to work inside your termux partition ($HOME/$PREFIX). There it works, I've tested the same command, and I got the result below:

```
~/git-repo/test $ npm i ts-node-dev -D

added 65 packages, and audited 66 packages in 2s

6 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

There are some workarounds to make it work in the ~/storage partition, but you'll possibly have other access related issues. If you need to access the files outside the termux (some IDE app, for instance), I explained it in another very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72407828/edit-cloned-file-from-git-on-android-termux/72501287#72501287).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep installing in `/storage/emulated` you can use the `--no-bin-links` command at the end of your npm command. e.g :

```bash
npm install ts-node-dev -D --no-bin-links
```

This code works for me